# Change nested vuetify list color so it's white or has no active class

Tags: sass, vuetify.js

I have this list I created, which looks like this:

```
<v-list class="criteria-list" color="#f2f4f7">
  <v-list-group
    v-for="criterion in criteria"
    :key="criterion.name"
    v-model="criterion.active"
    no-action
  >
    <template v-slot:activator>
      <v-list-item-content>
        <v-list-item-title
          class="text-uppercase"
          v-text="criterion.name"
        ></v-list-item-title>
      </v-list-item-content>
    </template>

    <v-list-item-group
      v-for="attribute in criterion.attributes"
      :key="attribute.name"
      multiple
      active-class=""
    >
      <v-list-item @click="addFilter(attribute)">
        <template v-slot:default="{ active }">
          <v-list-item-action>
            <v-checkbox :input-value="active"></v-checkbox>
          </v-list-item-action>

          <v-list-item-content>
            <v-list-item-title>
              {{ attribute.name }} ({{ attribute.count }})
            </v-list-item-title>
          </v-list-item-content>
        </template>
      </v-list-item>
    </v-list-item-group>
  </v-list-group>
</v-list>
```

I want it to look like this:

[image]

So, as you can see, I have applied `color="#f2f4f7"` to the master list, which has indeed changed the background colour, but it has done it for itself, and the groups also.
I tried setting the colour of the `v-list-item-group` but it's not setting the background-color of the group unless it's active:

[image]

This is using `color="pink"` as white doesn't do anything.
Does anyone know if it's possible to do what I want without having to override using `::v-deep`?

Answer (score 0):

you can do it with a css;

```
.v-list-item::before {
  background: transparent !important;
}
```

and , of course, **remove** the **color** attribute from the **v-list**

```
<v-list class="criteria-list">
    <v-list-group
      v-for="criterion in criteria"
      :key="criterion.name"
      v-model="criterion.active"
      no-action
    >
      <template v-slot:activator>
        <v-list-item-content>
          <v-list-item-title
            class="text-uppercase"
            v-text="criterion.name"
          ></v-list-item-title>
        </v-list-item-content>
      </template>

      <v-list-item-group
        v-for="attribute in criterion.attributes"
        :key="attribute.name"
        multiple
        active-class=""
      >
        <v-list-item @click="addFilter(attribute)">
          <template v-slot:default="{ active }">
            <v-list-item-action>
              <v-checkbox :input-value="active"></v-checkbox>
            </v-list-item-action>

            <v-list-item-content>
              <v-list-item-title>
                {{ attribute.name }} ({{ attribute.count }})
              </v-list-item-title>
            </v-list-item-content>
          </template>
        </v-list-item>
      </v-list-item-group>
    </v-list-group>
  </v-list>
```